# Gimp mouse wheel zoom resolution

Tags: gimp

Is there are way to change the amount a single increment on the mouse wheel zooms in the image when using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Mouse_wheel_scroll</kbd> to zoom.

I find that Gimp zooms too much per mouse wheel increment and I would like to reduce it.

I have found this to be a problem on both, Windows 10 and Ubuntu.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every piece of information I've been able to collect, including some tests of my own, shows that your objective is currently unavailable. One of the older references I've located dates to 2012 and suggests that many people have desired this ability, with zero success.

Another reference suggests that there may be an add-on or plug-in possible, but the complication arises in that Gimp has many keyboard shortcuts or feature implementations that would conflict with any such plug-in.

I suppose "no" is currently the correct answer, although not the desired one.

As this was my second draft, I inadvertently deleted links previously included. One reference to this conclusion can be found here:
http://www.gimpusers.com/forums/gimp-developer/15032-smooth-zoom
and another, with links that seem to repeat the desire without the solution:
https://mail.gnome.org/archives/gimp-developer-list/2012-October/msg00106.html

Comment: Can you provide the references? Just hinting at them is not really satisfactory.

Comment: I see. Further into one of these threads, there is the explanation for the current zoom steps: https://mail.gnome.org/archives/gimp-developer-list/2012-October/msg00113.html

Comment: "No" is the short answer to the question, the longer one would be "source is available, specifications and patches are welcome". If an attempt in that direction is made, I'd suggest to do this on the Linux platform, as the package management there makes it really easy to set up a working development environment with a few commands.